# UILabel NSAttributedString.link not clickable when contains Unicode string

Tags: ios, swift

when using normal text (English) it is work normal I can click able on link

here is code

```
let attText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 15)!])

let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
let matches = detector.matches(in: text, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count))

for match in matches {
    guard let range = Range(match.range, in: text) else { continue }
    let url = text[range]
    if let validURL = URL(string: String(url)) {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(validURL) {
            attText.addAttributes([.link : URL(string: String(url))!], range: match.range)
        }
    }
}
    
let label = UILabel()
label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = width
label.attributedText = attText
return label
```

[image: here is result image]
when test all English link can click and work fine

Comment: Do you have an working and not working example? Is the `.link` attribute set in both case? In theory, `UILabel` isn't done for that, you should use a `UITextView` instead (and with a little of modification, user won't see the difference).

Comment: @Larme please check again I've upload screenshot